# What do I need to know for Developing App Engine Connected Android Project?

Tags: android, google-app-engine

I am new to Android. I want to create an App, which interacts with the Server. I chose Google App Engine as the backend for this. I just wanted to know, What must I know before starting the development on Google App engine connected Android Project. The official docs from Google are not helping me out.

Comment: you dont need to do anything different in your android app. But i suggest you get the Google app engine plug-in for eclipse so that the app project and the google app engine project could de done in the same IDE.

Comment: Care to clarify what about the official docs are not helping you out?